# How to choose multiple files from file dialog and open at the same time and access them

Tags: python, pyqt5, qfiledialog

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys
 
 
def dialog():
    file , check = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()",
                    "", "All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py);;Text Files (*.txt)")
    if check:
        print(file)
 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QMainWindow()
win.setGeometry(400,400,300,300)
win.setWindowTitle("CodersLegacy")
  
button = QPushButton(win)
button.setText("Press")
button.clicked.connect(dialog)
button.move(50,50)
 
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the code to select and open a single file when I press a button. However, how can this is changed to select multiple files and open at the same time. I tried for the syntax, unfortunately, I could not find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames()` method, also the second value of the tuple that returns is not a check but a string that indicates the filter used, if you want to verify then you have to use the size of the filenames:

```py
filenames, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(
    None,
    "QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()",
    "",
    "All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py);;Text Files (*.txt)",
)
if filenames:
    for filename in filenames:
        print(filename)
```